# User chose whether download or stream mp4 media

Tags: php, download, streaming

I'd like to give the user the possibility to download or stream the same media. I tried this way (adding *download*) but it doesn't work:

```
<a target='_blank' href='http://another/site/file.mp4' download>DOWNLOAD</a>
<a target='_blank' href='http://another/site/file.mp4'>STREAMING</a>
```

I create the page using php 5.6

Note that the file is always the same: `http://another/site/file.mp4` and comes from a different domain (The `<a>` urls are in site1 and the media is in site2 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `download` attribute on `<a>` tags only work with the following:

- The URL must be the same origin as the HTML document.
- The browser must be Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Safari (10) or Opera (15)

I'm going to assume the URL is from another website, and that's why it's not working.

Comment: Exactly the content comes from another domain

Comment: @Timmy sorry, but forcing downloads from another domain is a security risk. That's why the browser won't allow it. Can you accept the answer.

Comment: But I've access to both domains: site1 and site2. If it's a security problem there are no chance to allow the direct dowload neither in the second domain? I don't see why it shouldn't be allowed, it's everything mine and other media file (`.mkv` for exampe) are available to download.

Comment: @Timmy on the server that contains the file. If have control, you can modify the response headers to tell the browser to force a download. What web server you're using will dedicate how to do it, and you should ask it as another question.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I'll ask in another question how to force download